# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I've got an application running on ASP.NET MVC 3 with Entity Framework Code First. In development I was using a SQL Compact database, however upon moving this to my virtual server, I am attempting to target SQL Express.

There were initially issues to do with a "CREATE DATABASE in master" error, which I got around by extracting the model from the SQL Compact database into an SQL script and executing that on the server to create the DB.

I have created a new connection string to point at the SQL Express instance, which uses the EF format:

```
<add name="LouiseClarkEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.LouiseClark.csdl|res://*/Models.LouiseClark.ssdl|res://*/Models.LouiseClark.msl;provider=System.Data.EntityClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=LouiseClark; User ID=<username>; Password=<password>&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The error I am now getting when navigating to a page that uses the DB, is:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

I have installed Entity Framework 4.1 on the server to try and see if this would solve the issue, but it didn't seem to do much good.

Snippet from the stack trace on error page:

```
[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1420567
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +35

[ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.]
```

Any help would be appreciated, as this has been bugging me for days now!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal connection string with code first.

```
<add name="LouiseClarkEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=LouiseClark; User ID=<username>; Password=<password>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Eranga however now the `context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false)` call in my custom initializer is returning false. I have copied the metadata table from the development DB to the server, and the tables match.

Answer (score 0):

On your second problem, and partly the cause of the first too...

what you did wrong is `which I got around by extracting the model from the SQL Compact database into an SQL script and executing that on the server to create the DB.`

You should use migration scripts for that - and use in PM console then `Update-Database -Script` to dump out what you need - then deploy that to the server Database.

Problem is that there are CF has its own table and data that needs to be initialized properly. If that doesn't match you'll end up with something like that.